# versioning change for alpa build in android and ios

Tags: android, ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am working on a mobile app which supports both android and iOS. The current play store version is v0.9.199 and  current version in alpha testing (internal testing) is v1.0.200 .

Now I need to change the versioning of the app to 4 numbers.

Can I release next version into alpa testing with new version as v1.0.0.201?

Comment: On Android the version number is a meaningless string and can be whatever you want.  There's a build number that's a monotonially increasing integer, that needs to go up if you want it to be recognized by the playstore as a new build.